# Ubuntu CLI full screen in Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

How to get full screen Ubuntu guest in Virtual Box in CLI mode. I don't have or want any GUI.
Can someone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this **Ctrl+Alt+F1** (F1 -F6) for tty full-screen terminal and Alt+F7 to exit it.

Comment: Or try the server OS?  pretty sure there's no GUI included by default.

Comment: are you looking to just boot into CLI or actually not want the GUI installed on the machine?

Comment: @CameronAziz I just want to boot into CLI. I would not mind GUI installed or not.

Comment: @Josh I tried Server OS. But it did not let me get full screen in VBox. Have you had any success with that. Let  me know.

Answer (score 2):

Send these keys to the virtual machine `Ctrl+Alt+F1`

Comment: Does not make it full screen for me :(

Comment: Try using the other Ctrl key on your keyboard. Virtualbox likes to use the right Ctrl key as a special key.

Comment: The virtual box becomes full screen obviously but not the CLI content. As it is the case with GUI

Answer (score 1):

If you want your guest OS to be full screen in your host OS, then you can do that by pressing `Ctrl+f`. Use the right Ctrl key.